# Can I prevent execute immediate from inserting on a read-only user

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl, privileges

I have a read-only user that has to have the execute privileges to specific packages.
These packages sometimes use `execute immediate` to insert values into tables.

I can see why it was built this way, however I need the package to throw an *Insufficient Privileges* error instead of just executing the modifying statements.

Is it possible to change the behaviour or build a workaround without changing the executed packages?

So read only user has:

```
GRANT SELECT ON table to READ_ONLY_USER;
GRANT EXECUTE, DEBUG ON package to READ_ONLY_USER;
```

Package contains:

```
query = 'INSERT INTO table VALUES (value)';
execute immediate query;
```

And I need an error when the user executes the package.

Comment: Actually you can't - unless you change the package. The package performs an `INSERT` and you grant `EXECUTE` on it, so you permit the INSERT. There are many solutions to achieve your requirement but **all** require a modification of the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following example. Shortly, keyword is `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` while creating that PL/SQL program unit.

Connected as `MIKE` (who owns table and procedure and grant `SCOTT` privileges to use them):

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL>
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    authid current_user
  3  is
  4  begin
  5    execute immediate 'insert into mike.test values (1)';
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> grant select on test to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant execute on p_test to scott;

Grant succeeded.

SQL>
```

Connected as `SCOTT`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SCOTT"
SQL>
SQL> select * From mike.test;

        ID
----------
         1

SQL> exec mike.p_test;
BEGIN mike.p_test; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
ORA-06512: at "MIKE.P_TEST", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 1


SQL>
```

---

Without it, `SCOTT` is able to insert values into `MIKE`'s table:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion@orcl
Connected.
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2  is                                      --> no more authid current_user
  3  begin
  4    execute immediate 'insert into mike.test values (2)';
  5  end;
  6  /

Procedure created.

SQL> connect scott/tiger@orcl
Connected.
SQL> exec mike.p_test;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From mike.test;

        ID
----------
         1
         2

SQL>
```

Comment: thanks alot! is there a way though to pass on `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to packages, used within the original package? i.e. building a wrapper? looking through google, it looks like there is not, which means I'd have to modify the executed packages

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure you can "pass" it. A wrapper? Don't know, try it and see what happens :)